# Import Error on ChartDataProvider Webpart

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, chart-web-part

My Sharepoint project contains a visual Webpart which retrieves data and works fine.
In addition to that, I want to display some Chart webparts which visualize this data. 
In order to do so, i added a new item to the project (WebPart; not Visual Webpart) in which I create a datatable, add data to it and a ConnectionPoint.

the problem occurs after deployment, when i try to add this webpart to the page. There is simply an alert "Webpart cannot be importet".

Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
    <Module Name="KategorieChartDataProvider" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
      <File Path="KategorieChartDataProvider\KategorieChartDataProvider.webpart" Url="KategorieChartDataProvider.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
      </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

.webpart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="TestProjekt.KategorieChartDataProvider.KategorieChartDataProvider, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">KategorieChartDataProvider</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Description will follow</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Is there an obvious error I am missing?

Kind regards

/edit: I am using WSP builder to deploy if that information is useful to you
/edit2: I found a partial solution. The error was insinde the webpartcode. I had the following code in the constructor for the KategorieChartDataProvider class.

DataTable _table = new DataTable();

```
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = typeof(string);
        col.ColumnName = "Kategorie";
        _table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn();
        col.DataType = typeof(int);
        col.ColumnName = "Value";
        _table.Columns.Add(col);
        foreach (var item in repo.GetAllCategories())
        {
            DataRow row = new DataRow();
            row["Kategorie"] = item._name;
            row["Value"] = item._val;
            _table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

This bit of code is now located in the OnInit method. However, if I use this webpart now (I can add it to the page) I am getting a Null Reference Exception.

> [NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine
>   Objektinstanz festgelegt.]
>   TestProjekt.KategorieChartDataProvider.KategorieChartDataProvider.GetTableData(TableCallback
>   callback) +68
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.Charting.WebPart.SetTableProvider(IWebPartTable
>   provider) +294
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler
>   verursacht.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +1255
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +38    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.ConsumerConnectionPoint.SetObject(Control
>   control, Object data) +98
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartConnection.Activate() +1980
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ActivateConnections()
>   +439    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.OnPageLoadComplete(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +70    System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +0    System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
>   +11057518    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3160

any ideas on this one?